# Underline then vertical line: How to write this notation?

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

Looks like a combination of underline and lower-right-corner symbol.

[image: Picture]

Comment: Is it used in an area connected with the time value of money?

Comment: I slightly retagged. `tex-core` is absolutely not the correct tag for this.

Comment: What is the utility of this notation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite sure how that should be used but here's a way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\foo}[1]{%
   \hbox{\vtop{\hbox{\mathsurround0pt$#1$\kern1pt}\kern1pt\hrule}\vrule}%
}

\begin{document}
$abc\foo{abc}def\foo{def}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If it' supposed to work across math styles you can add the usual `\mathpalette`

```
\newcommand*{\foo}{\mathpalette\fooaux}
\newcommand*{\fooaux}[2]{\hbox{\vtop{\hbox{\mathsurround0pt$#1#2$\kern1pt}\kern1pt\hrule}\vrule}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tabular`. Choose a better name than `\command`.

```
documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\command}[1]{\mathpalette\command@{#1}}
\newcommand{\command@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}|@{}}
  \raisebox{0pt}[\height][\dimexpr\depth+0.5pt]{$\m@th#1#2$\kern0.5pt}\\\hline
  \end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$avcx\command{av}$

$avcx\command{ay}$

$\scriptstyle avcx\command{ay}$

\end{document}
```

With `\arraystretch` set to zero no strut is inserted; however a small clearance has been added below and on the right.

[image]